# Can I develop for android applications by using CLI

Tags: java, android, eclipse, command-line

I've start developing android applications.
but My PC has so poor  resource cpu and  ram for using eclipse 
so I'd like to develop by CLI javac..

How can I use CLI for developing android?

Comment: You can develop just fine, but I hope you have a device to test with because the emulator requires a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do everything you need from CLI: http://d.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically after you have downloaded and installed the SDK and all the components, you just type 'android start project' with the right arguments and this is preparing everything for you.

Use your preferred editor to write some code in the src/...(package path).../ folder, you can also add any jar file in the libs and the layout or other resources, everything will be picked up automatically

After that, just call 'ant compile' or 'ant install' from the root folder of your application to compile or to compile and install on a real or virtual device.

Call 'android' without any argument and follow the right menus to create or launch a virtual device.
There are also other tools you can launch directly from the command line like ddms, hierarchy viewer and such.

(I am all for vi editing and really hate Eclipse for a lot of different reasons, including eating computer resources for nothing). Doing Android development on the command line is really not that difficult and makes your code so much cleaner (at least as clean as you make it)

Answer (score 0):

"After that, just call 'ant compile'"

I built a CLI app and used "javac" instead of "ant compile" and it was MUCH faster.

======================================

Is the above wrong or just confusing?
I meant to say javac is much better than GRADLE, but to a certain extent both are true.  Sorry.